# Как получить данные пользователя из БД FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

Мне нужно после логина пользователя, получить информацию о нем из БД (ну, допустим, просто почту вывести)
Делаю через `fastapi-users JWT`. Там есть такая функция:

```py
async def on_after_login(
    self, user: User,
    request: Optional[Request] = None,
):
    print(f"User {user.id} logged in.")
```

Просто её копирую, но получаю ошибку:

> "TypeError: UserManager.on_after_login() takes 2 positional argument
> but 4 were given"

Что не так?

Comment: `"Просто её копирую"` - куда копируешь?

Comment: Нужно приводить полный стек-трейс ошибки в вопросе, а не пересказывать её.